# Finding theoretical mechanism of sodium thiosulphate and hydrochloric acid

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, redox, kinetics

In class we conducted an experiment where we timed reactions between sodium thiosulphate and hydrochloric acid. We kept the concentration of the $\ce{HCl}$ constant, while changing the concentrations of sodium thiosulphate.

We then graphed this data to discover there is a linear relationship between the concentration of thiosulphate and 1/time, indicating the it is a first order reaction. This means in the rate determining step there will be one thiosulphate ion.

In the analysis question it asks you to come up with a theoretical mechanism. I'm having alot of trouble with this because the first order relationship found on the graph indicates there is 1 thiosulphate ion in the rate determining step, but the overall equation also has one thiosulphate ion.

Can anyone help me out, I have tried multiple methods but none seem to add up to the overall equation.

$$\ce{2 HCl (aq) + Na2S2O3 (aq) -> 2 NaCl (aq) + SO2 (g) + S (s) + H2O (l)}$$

Comment: I think you are running into problems partly because the reaction isn't first order and partly because the real mechanism is fairly complex. It looks like this lab came from [Flinn Scientific](https://www.flinnsci.com/globalassets/flinn-scientific/all-free-pdfs/dc91860.pdf?v=b9e291b6202a46a5b324013f57e3f533) and they suggest a pretty convoluted mechanism for the reaction.

Comment: You can format mathematical and chemical expressions on Chemistry.SE using MathJax; [this post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86) contains further details.